# How to turn on Peripheral mode in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ads

I am creating an application which will send the BLE advertisement in android. I am using Intrinsyc eval kit for Android (snapdragon 805) APQ8084. It has android OS version of 5.1.1 but seems that the peripheral mode is not on. Because of it I am not able to send advertisement beacon from it.

Is there a way to turn on the peripheral mode in Android?

Thank You,

Comment: GAP profile is supposed to support the option to enable BLE advertisement, did you try GAP API's?

Comment: No I didn't tried that. I'll look for it's example. If you have any can you please guide me on this?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeAdvertiser.html might help you